Issue with dmidecode to Retrieve CPU Details etc
Overview
I'm experiencing an issue with the dmidecode command on a system with an 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 CPU. The dmidecode command does not show complete details about the CPU and other hardware components.
System Configuration

CPU: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Kernel: Linux 6.1.0-18-amd64
dmidecode version: 3.4

dmidecode Output
The output from the dmidecode command shows limited and outdated information.
root@faiserver:~# dmidecode 
# dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.5 present.
10 structures occupying 450 bytes.
Table at 0x000E1000.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 20 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: innotek GmbH
    Version: VirtualBox
    Release Date: 12/01/2006
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 128 kB
    Characteristics:
        ISA is supported
        PCI is supported
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: innotek GmbH
    Product Name: VirtualBox
    Version: 1.2
    Serial Number: 0
    UUID: e83f6988-828d-5142-a0e2-2bca4c199fc3
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: Not Specified
    Family: Virtual Machine

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation
    Product Name: VirtualBox
    Version: 1.2
    Serial Number: 0
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
    Location In Chassis: Not Specified
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 13 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation
    Type: Other
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 126, 42 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 126, 15 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 126, 28 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 11, 7 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: vboxVer_6.1.50
    String 2: vboxRev_161033

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 128, 8 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        80 08 04 00 FF C5 2A 00

Handle 0xFEFF, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table

root@faiserver:~#

DMI Table Directory
The DMI table directory shows that the tables are present.
root@faiserver:~# ls -l /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/
total 0
-r-------- 1 root root 450 Jun 21 03:27 DMI
-r-------- 1 root root  31 Jun 21 03:27 smbios_entry_point

BIOS/UEFI Version
The BIOS version is here :
root@faiserver:~# sudo dmidecode -t bios
# dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 20 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: innotek GmbH
    Version: VirtualBox
    Release Date: 12/01/2006
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 128 kB
    Characteristics:
        ISA is supported
        PCI is supported
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported

root@faiserver:~#

dmidecode version
root@faiserver:~# dmidecode --v
3.4
root@faiserver:~# 


CPU Details with lshw Command
The lshw command correctly identifies the CPU model, indicating that the hardware itself is properly recognized by the operating system.
root@faiserver:~# lshw | grep Intel
          product: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          vendor: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
root@faiserver:~#

OS Details
root@faiserver:~# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
root@faiserver:~# uname -a
Linux faiserver 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@faiserver:~#
``


Not a programming problem. Try [unix.se] or [su], when in doubt contact the maintainers ...

I'm gonna need you to precise what exactly are you expecting from the command ? Do you have any example ?
